# URL for public folders in Exchange 2010

Tags: php, exchange-2010, public-folders

I am trying to access a public calendar on Exchange Server 2010 using php, but I cannot find the right URL.

Previously, when the server was running 2003, I could use the URL http://server.domain.com/public/calendar and then parse the data.

But when I try this in 2010 I am redirected to http:// server.domain.com/owa. I've tried updating my URL from public to owa, but it doesn't return anything.

Any idea how I can find the URL for this public calendar?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to be accessing it from PHP wouldn't you want to be using [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx)?

Comment: :O It does indeed look like that is what I want to do, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Microsoft is [de-emphasizing](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2008/03/31/448537.aspx) public folders some functionality was not updated for 2007/2010.  For example in 2007 you can no longer access public folders using the Light version Outlook Web Access.  I am not certain, but I suspect that the problem you are having is just another de-emphasized feature.

As I mentioned in a comment you can still access public folders from PHP using [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx).  Here is a good [article](http://www.howtoforge.com/talking-soap-with-exchange) that I found useful in creating a PHP script to retrieve some data from the Exchange server.

Comment: Thanks heaps Zoredache, I've got it to work now thanks to the help of that article and the php-ews library.